# 'Attempt to get length of null array' while directory and files exist - fresh install

Tags: java, arrays

Part of my code sorts files and reads their names:

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.csv");
File[] files = directory.listFiles(fileFilter);
Arrays.sort(files, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
```

On fresh install when directory doesn't exist - app creates it +some empty files and everything works flawlessly.

The problem occurs when I try to install app once again after I had removed it (but directory with files remains). App throws an error while starting, and starts only after removing directory.

It looks like app can't read existing files despite granted permissions in manifest. But when I remove those files and let the app to create them again - it works. It works even after I paste some aditional files to the directory.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: "What do I do wrong?" - it's difficult to say since you shared with us only irrelevant code ;)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/vasyl91/muse-sleep-tracker-and-arduino-light-therapy/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/sleep_tracker/components/managers/CSVGraphHelper.java) is full code ;)

Comment: please share stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Don't assume that **WildcardFileFilter()** knows exactly where your `.csv` files are located. Be path specific. What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving us very little information about your actual problem. But it is likely that the `listFiles` method is returning `null`. The documentation on the return value is (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles-java.io.FileFilter-)):

> An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in
>   the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be
>   empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract
>   pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

You should verify that `directory` in your code exists, and possibly create it or simply don't read it if it doesn't.

Comment: The thing is that the directory and files exist and `listFiles` returns `null`. When it doesn't - app creates it and problem is gone. But i want to read existing ones.

Comment: You are checking for `directory.exists()`, you can use `directory.isDirectory()` to check if the `File` actually is a directory (and not a file, in which case it'd also return `null`). If it still fails, try to create the directory yourself and see if it works that way. It's still possible that whatever generates your directory affects some permission settings.